# Amazon ElasticBeanstalk configuration not working

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have able to successfully deploy a php application using git in elastic beanstalk, but the configuration files doesnot work. I created a .ebextensions folder on my root application folder and created a config file with the following command:

```
container_commands:
  00_make_assets:
    command: "sudo mkdir /var/app/current/assets"
```

I get the following error message on the dashboard

```
 Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] command failed with error code 1: Error occurred during build: Command 00_make_assets failed.
```

All I want to do is create a folder and give 777 permission to it.

The output in  the log file (/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log) shows:

```
[2014-10-17T11:01:43.487Z] ERROR [2341]  : Command CMD-AppDeploy failed!
[2014-10-17T11:01:43.488Z] INFO  [2341]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","truncated":"false","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"[CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] command failed with error code 1: Error occurred during build: Command 00_make_assets failed","returncode":1,"events":[]}]}
```

Has anyone been in this situation? How can this issue be solved? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: can you look at the full logs? There are other log files which will point you to the full error message. Try following the instructions here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html

Comment: Did you try the command without `sudo`? (I think Beanstalk deploys as root so no need to sudo)